# Neo4j Join from CSV

Tags: neo4j

I am the following sample nodes:

`{
  "name": "host_1",
  "id": 0
}
{
  "name": "host_2",
  "id": 1
}`

Then I have connections/authentications between those nodes in a CSV file.

`{
  "src_id": "291",
  "dest_id": "162"
}
{
  "src_id": "291",
  "dest_id": "257"
}`

I am trying to build the relationships (authentications between hosts) with the CSV file, but I'm having trouble getting the query finalized before I can create the relationship. 
Is there a way to make an alias for a match similar to a SQL join?

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///redteam_connections.csv" AS row
MATCH (n:nodes {id: toInteger(row.dest_id)}), (n:nodes {id: toInteger(row.src_id)})`

I'd like to make an alias such as

`(n:nodes {id: toInteger(row.dest_id)}) AS dest_node, (n:nodes {id: toInteger(row.src_id)}) AS src_node
RETURN src_node.name, dest_node.name`
based on my research, this doesn't appear possible. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Is it a limitation or problem with the structure of my dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is you're using the same variable, `n`, to refer to both nodes, so that isn't going to work. If you want to use `src_node` and `dest_node` as variables, you can:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///redteam_connections.csv" AS row
MATCH (destNode:nodes {id: toInteger(row.dest_id)}), (srcNode:nodes {id: toInteger(row.src_id)})
CREATE (destNode)-[:AUTHENTICATION]->(srcNode)
```

You definitely want to add in index on :nodes(id) so your lookups are fast, and you may want to reconsider the `:nodes` label. By convention labels tend to be capitalized and singular (plural is usually used for when you actually collect() items into a list), so `:Node` would be more appropriate here.

If your CSV is large, I also recommend you [use periodic commit](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) to allow batching and prevent blowing your heap.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestions! Worked like a charm. Going to blow this setup away and start with proper naming conventions.